# ESI Juli@ - 2 channels in control panel, but Audacity recording only 1

Tags: audio-recording, recording, audacity

So I am trying to capture audio from my Marantz PM5004, everything is plugged in just fine and ESI Juli@ is detecting the audio playing from both L and R channels, but when I try to record it using Audacity, all I get is right channel. Any ideas what is going on here?

[image: The screenshot]

Comment: It may be a track assignment issue, try to record all four channels at the same time (Audacity allows for that, if it is recognizing the Julia correctly there should be an option for that in the channels selection dropdown) and see if the missing left channel appears on one of the other tracks.